# Bind new modal field in asp.net core modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My code was working file until i added a new field in modal which has only get method

```
     public bool hasShiftingRequest { 
        //this field is not in database 
        //it is being calculated everytime you access it
        get
        {                   
            return _context.AssetShifting.Where(a => a.assetId == this.Id & a.status.Equals("REQUESTED")).Any();                
        }
    }
```

But it is causing error during my edit method which is binding fronted data with modal
(Basically problem during Binding)

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,make_model,lot,username,email")] AssetDataPc assetDataPc)
```

and I am getting this error
[image]

Please Help !

**EDIT**
My assetPC modal

```
 public class AssetDataPc
{        
    public readonly AssetManagementContext _context;

    
    public AssetDataPc(AssetManagementContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int ram { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Remarks")]
    public string remarks { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "QR Code Status")]
    public string qr_code_status { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Last updated")]
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Screen Size")]
    public string screen_size { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Color")]

    public string rowColor { get; set; } = "";
    
    public bool hasShiftingRequest { 
        //this field is not in database 
        //it is being calculated everytime you access it
        get
        {                   
            return _context.AssetShifting.Where(a => a.assetId == this.Id & a.status.Equals("REQUESTED")).Any();                
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

my edit (POST( method is some what like this

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("remarks,qr_code_status,email")] AssetDataPc assetDataPc)
        {
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {              
                    assetDataPc.updated_at = DateTime.Now;
                    _context.Update(assetDataPc);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
```

**EDIT 3**

My edit (Get) method:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {

        var assetDataPc = await _context.AssetDataPcs.FindAsync(id);
        if (assetDataPc == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(assetDataPc);
    }
```

Comment: Please share `AssetDataPc` code

Comment: Not able to add more code 
Stack Overflow forbidding it

Comment: can shorten assetPC model. and add more info for us to understand more.

Comment: in your EDIT 2, this edit method is where you got error?

Comment: No its not even hitting on edit method and fails before it

Comment: @Asherguru may be this is the wrong way to use database context inside  modal classes,Any other way u know?

Comment: @parthrajpanchal do you have other Edit method for loading data? there are 2 - Get and Post. Yours is Post. I need see your Get one.

Comment: @Asherguru I have added GET method

Comment: @parthrajpanchal i edited my post. can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasShiftingRequest is not in your database?

Then use [NotMapped] if you need to use extra column without adding this column in database so that entity framework core will not check this matching column between model class and table in database.

```
[NotMapped]
public bool? hasShiftingRequest { get; set; }
```

Remove AssetManagementContext from your AssetDataPc model. Like this.

```
public class AssetDataPc
{        
    [NotMapped]
    public bool? hasShiftingRequest { get; set; }
}
```

### "Get" Edit method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{

    var assetDataPc = await _context.AssetDataPcs.FindAsync(id);
    if (assetDataPc == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
        assetDataPc.hasShiftingRequest = _context.AssetShifting.Where(a => a.assetId == assetDataPc.Id & a.status.Equals("REQUESTED")).Any();

    return View(assetDataPc);
}
```

**Solution**

--dont use DbContext in modal classes

--use [NotMapped] to avoid creating database field

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219184/discussion-on-answer-by-asherguru-bind-new-modal-field-in-asp-net-core-modal).

Answer (score 1):

As the exception states `AssetDataPc` should have a parameterless constructor in order to be binded. When you added this constructor

```
public AssetDataPc(AssetManagementContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

it started failing.
Consider moving `hasShiftingRequest` logic outside the class and just map result to plain property.

Comment: Then how can i use database context inside modal class ?

Comment: @parthrajpanchal That's the point, don't use context inside viewmodel classes. Use it outside this class

Comment: i guess this may be correct. you can bind hasShiftingRequest in your AssetDataPc's select repository. please post your Edit's get or post data too.

Comment: @Alexander Its not ViewModal , it is simple modal mapped with database table 
and no idea how can i use it outside the class?

Comment: if your edit is to update data, you can set assetDataPc.hasRequestShifting = _context.AssetShifting.Where(a => a.assetId == assetDataPc.Id & a.status.Equals("REQUESTED")).Any(); in AssetDataPc's repository before _context.SaveChanges();

Comment: @Alexander here hasShiftingRequest is not in database . It has only get method which calculates the result when its called. There is no setter method.

Comment: @Alexander I think         public readonly AssetManagementContext _context;
 is causing the error as it needs the default value of it when creating new object of assetPcData.

Comment: @Alexander Any solution pls?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message said, Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. So, you could try to add the default AssetDataPc constructor for the AssetDataPc class.

```
 public class AssetDataPc
{        
    public readonly AssetManagementContext _context;

    public AssetDataPc(){} //add default constructor

    public AssetDataPc(AssetManagementContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    ...     
    
    public bool hasShiftingRequest { 
        //this field is not in database 
        //it is being calculated everytime you access it
        get
        {                   
            return _context.AssetShifting.Where(a => a.assetId == this.Id & a.status.Equals("REQUESTED")).Any();                
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

need context everytime i retrieve data 

_context was null.

Comment: i just learn not to use DbContext in model class ever